# Django authentication: query by current user from foreign key

Tags: python, django, authentication, models

I'm trying to filter the below model by the current user, but I can't seem to get it right.  I think it is a simple solution, but everything I try fails.  It is not my AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.  I just want for a currently logged in user to be able to filter out all of their preferred organizations.

```
class UserOrgConnections(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    orgs = models.ManyToManyField(Organizations)
```

Comment: What exactly fails? There are some error message?

Comment: What is written is working.  I just can't figure out how to write the query that I want.  I can try some different things and show some error messages and attempt, but I think the answer to my question should be simple for an even slightly experienced developer (which I am not).  Everything I'm finding in the searches assumes that you will be pulling a variable from the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE, which this is not.  I'm just having a difficult time getting the query written.  If it were I would do something like this   'county = user.county.all()' but it is not.

Comment: I should say 'orgs = user.orgs.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to filter the `UserOrgConnections` model by current user, then access the `orgs` values.

Within your view, you can access the current user through the request variable, like so: `request.user`.

Here's the simplest way of getting all the `orgs` values of the logged-in user:

```
user = request.user
userorgs = UserOrgConnections.objects.filter(user = user)
# at this point, you have all instances of UserOrgConnections
# for which the current user is the user value

print userorgs.values('orgs')       # as ValuesQuerySet
print [x.orgs for x in userorgs]    # as Python list
```

---

If you need clarification on any of that, or if I misread what it is you're trying to do, let me know in the comments.

Comment: That is perfect!  How do I get my 'org_name' to show on the list rather than the primary key - if you don't mind?

Comment: If the name of the field on the `Organizations` model is `org_name`, then you would do `print [x.orgs.org_name for x in userorgs]`. In this case, `orgs` values are instances of another model, so their attributes can be accessed in the same way you access the values of a `UserOrgConnections` instance. Let me know if that works out the way you wanted it to.

Comment: I feel silly because I have no idea how to utilize your last recommendation.  I actually need to take the results given and .filter them into several different queries.  While your recommendation may do exactly what I am asking, I'm not sure how to assign that print statement into a variable that I can then filter to create multiple different lists.  For instance, when I am done, I need to be able to filter it using statements similar to the following.  ' newspolitics = MyNews.objects.filter(news_orgs=userorgs).filter(news_orgs__org_type__pk=5).order_by('-date')'

Comment: As you might have expected, after some playing, I realized that this works exactly as you posted.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting 'Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field.'